# Select statement in SQL Server returns null while fetching values using email in where; unable to fetch data using values with dots using select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, backend

I'm trying to get password from email address but the problem is that the selection query won't read the the values after dots in the emails column and returns null results. I've tried `PARSENAME()` and `RIGHT()` functions to get it read the full email address. But no luck there. I've put my query statement below.

```
select Password 
from Faculty 
where Email = 'john.carson@outlook.com'
```

I'm not getting the password that belongs to that email address, instead all I get is null. The datatype is both email and password fields are `nvarchar(100)`. And there are 5 records with different emails one of which is this. I'm sure the problem's rising because of the dots, because I tried using dummy data in email as like johncarson@com and I got the password respective to that. I'm using SQL Server as my database engine.

Comment: If the query you showed us really returns empty set, then it means that no record has that email.

Comment: what is the datatype of Email column ?

Comment: It will help if you can show sample data for faculty table with email you mentioned above

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f084/1 - As you can see, the query works fine. There must be some other issue with your data.

Comment: It should be your data. Try `where Email LIKE 'john%'`. Check the `Email` column for any unprintable character

Answer (score 0):

I Hope, It will be work

```
select Password
from Faculty
where Email like 'john.carson@outlook.com'
```

Comment: I copied and pasted it. But still no where. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with dummy data but it's working please check with Like clause may be any space is exists in Email field.

```
Declare @Faculty Table (Email Varchar(300),Password varchar(20))
Insert into @Faculty VALUES ('john.carson@outlook.com','123'),('john1.carson@outlook.com','12335'),('john2.carson@outlook.com','12356')

select Password 
from @Faculty 
where Email = 'john.carson@outlook.com'
```

Comment: No there aren't any spaces. I dunno how did that worked for you, even though I tried using like clause but nothing.

Comment: Please check with this where Email LIKE  '%john.carson@outlook.com%' and please make sure this email is exists.